# Работа с пакетом Newtonsoft.Json в Yandex.Cloud

Tags: .net, nuget, yandex-cloud

При тестировании облачной функции в облаке яндекса получаю следующую ошибку:
{
"ErrorMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.",
"ErrorType": "FunctionException",
"StackTrace": null
}

Сам пакет Newtonsoft.Json был подключен с помощью NuGet. В zip-архиве файл Newtonsoft.Json.dll есть. Как можно исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать более раннюю версию пакета. У меня получилось с версией 12.0.2:

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2"/>
```